# Java image Tile Processing, byte binary image

Tags: java, pixel

I'm processing the large **tiff** image in **java**. My object is just read pixel value, calculate the ink area.

The tiff image is black & white image, byte binary image.
So I think pixel values are either 0 or 1 that white is 1, black is 0. 
But some sample files are correct. some files are not.
In some files 0 is black, 1 is white.

Is it possible?

The common point is 0:black, 1:white file is processed in windows photo editor.
0:white, 1:black is processed in EskoArtwork imaging engine.

Can the definition of an image pixel change depending on the engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tiff image is black & white image, byte binary image. So I think pixel values are either 0 or 1 that white is 1, black is 0. But some sample files are correct. some files are not. In some files 0 is black, 1 is white.
>
> Is it possible?

Absolutely. This is specified in the [TIFF Tag PhotometricInterpretation](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/photometricinterpretation.html).  An excerpt is:

```
IFD           Image
Code          262 (hex 0x0106)
Name          PhotometricInterpretation
LibTiff name  TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC
Type          SHORT
Count         1
Default       None
Description

The color space of the image data.

The specification considers these values baseline:

0 = WhiteIsZero. For bilevel and grayscale images: 0 is imaged as white.
1 = BlackIsZero. For bilevel and grayscale images: 0 is imaged as black.
...
```

You could have found this easily by searching "bilevel tiff tag" as the second link in Google.

Comment: Thanks ! It really helped a lot :)

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer so others will know it was the solution.